# React input state not updating with update function which sets state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I am trying to get a modal on my page to get and update its value based on the state of the component, and the update function called onChange.

Currently it looks like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
   name: '',
  }
}

updatedName = e => {
  this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
}

render() {
                <div className="modal__content__wrapper">
                    <div className="modal--display">
                        <label className='modal--label'> Name</label>
                        <input
                            className='modal--input'
                            onChange={this.updateName}
                            value={this.state.name}
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
}
```

It seems so basic but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It only seems to update state to one letter, and then rewrites that letter every time, and never displays it within the input.

Comment: `onChange={() => this.updatedName}`

Comment: Solved. I needed to change the value prop to defaultValue, and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onChange={this.updateName}
```

I think you are missing .bind(this). Try,

```
this.updateName.bind(this)
```

Update,

It could be that your function name has a typo.

You have this.updateName in return statement and this.updatedName in function definition (note "d" at in update"d"Name).

Comment: Yeah, that is a spelling mistake I typed in here but its not in my code

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `super()` and `return()`. Also the `updatedName` is misspelled when you invoke it.

```
constructor() {
 super();
  this.state = {
   name: '',
  }
}

updatedName = e => {
 this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
}

render() {
 return(
   <div className="modal__content__wrapper">
     <div className="modal--display">
     <label className='modal--label'> Name</label>
       <input
         className='modal--input'
         onChange={this.updatedName}
         value={this.state.name}
       />
     </div>
    </div>
  )
 }
```